# How change scene in JavaFX with FXML file?

Tags: java, fxml, javax

I have a little question about change scene in JavaFX.
I want to hide first scene and show next scene, after button click on.
My main scene id is "welcomeScene" (start.fxml) and second scene id is "aboutmeScene" (aboutme.fxml). The fxml files has same path and same folder/package.

Controller class code:

```
   @FXML
   private AnchorPane welcomeScene;

   @FXML
   private void aboutme(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
     AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("aboutme.fxml"));
     welcomeScene.getChildren().setAll(pane);

   }
```

When I click on my button I have this errors in console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
```

Other events ex.  System.exit(0); works. 
What I doing wrong? Someone can tell me how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
I moved "aboutme.fxml" to \bin\Controllers That's is.

Answer (score 0):

I know some time passed, but mabye this will help someone in the future:

If your fxml file is somewhere in the resource folder or in a subfolder of the resource folder in your project, you have to use a relative path to load it in java that is starting with a "/" character. The resource folder is located in the same Folder as the src folder of your project is.
If you load the fxml folder from inside your src directory or any of its subdirectories, you usually can use an absolute path or a relative path without the leading "/" character.

I am not sure why, but that is how java wants you to adress the resources in the resource folder. This is not only the case concerning fxml files but all other file types located outside the src folder / in the resource folder aswell.